# A Quick Question about DeRham Cohomology

Tags: differential-topology

I was going through some lectures, then I realised that they compute the DeRham Cohomology of $\mathbb{R}^0$ and when they wanted to compute the compactly supported DeRham Cohomology then they used the fact that since $\mathbb{R}^0$ is a compact space, the DeRham Cohomology groups of usual and compactly supported coincide.

Is it true in general?
That both is DeRham Cohomology coincide for any compact manifold $M$.

I was thinking about concluding something using poincare duality. That is since

$$H^q(M)=H^{n-q}_c(M)$$ where $M$ is an n-manifold.

If I assume it to be compact then I get $$H^q_c(M)=H^q(M)=H^{n-q}_c(M)$$

So $$H^q_c(M)=H^{n-q}_c(M)$$ for a compact manifold $M$. Does this look correct. Any nice conclusion using this?

Comment: Do you know the difference between the definitions of de Rham cohomology and compact supported de Rham cohomology?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, Yes. I am using that equality because of poincare duality lemma

Comment: My comment refers to your first question (is this true in general?). You don't need Poincaré duality for that. What is the difference in the definitions of the two cohomology groups?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, the difference comes from the space of $k-$differential forms. The differential forms are taken to be of form $\omega=f dx_{i_1}dx_{i_2}\dots dx_{i_k}$ where the function $f$ is compact. Further the maps are defined accordingly. Now when the manifold $M$ is compact then I will get its support to be closed subset of compact space which seem to be compact. Hence both will coincide in case of compact manifolds.

Comment: Exactly! You've answered your own question.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, yes that cool but I am wondering if we can conclude something nice about the Cohomology of a compact manifold using Poincare's Duality? That is I think for example for a manifold of dimension $6$, I will get that $H^0(M)=H^6(M)$ ; $H^1(M)=H^5(M)$ ; $H^2(M)=H^4(M)$ and so on. I think this is very interesting result but I am not quite sure.

Comment: note that it depends upon the dimension of the manifold, and that the manifold is compact. For example for $M=S^n$, we have $H^0(M)=H^n(M)=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes. For example, the Euler characteristic of a closed odd-dimensional manifold is zero. See Corollary 3.37 of Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

As established in the comments, if $M$ is compact then $H^k(M) = H^k_c(M)$ because every form has compact support. In particular, for a closed orientable $n$-manifold, we have

$$H^k_c(M) = H^k(M) \cong H^{n-k}(M) = H^{n-k}_c(M).$$

If the manifold is not compact, then these two groups may not be isomorphic.

**Example:** Consider the non-compact manifold $M = S^2\times\mathbb{R}$.

For a (potentially non-compact) orientable $n$-manifold, we always have $H^k(M) \cong (H^{n-k}_c(M))^*$, see Remark $5.7$ of *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology* by Bott and Tu. So $0 = H^1(M) \cong (H^2_c(M))^*$ and therefore $H^2_c(M) = 0$. On the other hand, $\mathbb{R} \cong H^2(M) \cong (H^1_c(M))^*$, so $H^1_c(M) \cong \mathbb{R} \not\cong 0 = H^2_c(M)$.